# how to obtain <= symbol in an R character vector

Tags: r, math, symbols

I need to obtain the less than or equals symbol (≤ ie not <=) in an R character vector.
The character vector will provide the "slab" labels for metafor.

So I'd like

```
  txt<-c("<=2", "3-5", "6-7",">=8")
```

but with proper less/greater than or equal symbols

and later

```
forest( ..... slab=txt ...)
```

So

```
txt<-c(expression(1 <= 2), "3-5", "6-7",">=8")
```

runs OK as "1 <= 2" is a proper R expression but thats not what I want.
I want just <=2 not 1 <= 2 but something like

```
txt<-c(expression(<= 2), "3-5", "6-7",">=8")
```

won't work

Answer (score 3):

```
txt<-c( paste0(intToUtf8(8804), "2"), "3-5", "6-7",paste0(intToUtf8(8805), "8"))
txt
# [1] "≤2"  "3-5" "6-7" "≥8"
```

Comment: thats fantastic and many thanks, Luke. As you show that fixes the character vector perfectly. Unfortunately when I use that vector to create row labels using slab in the metafor forest function that labels for the plot shows those symbols as just = signs. I didn't expect that problem. Maybe I need to ask a question on metafor on the R-help list

Comment: sorry I think that the labels you suggest work sometimes. It is quite strange as you see from this example - it works but when I uncomment the labs3 change the <= symbol changes to = - I can't have both changes working together  sigh library(metafor)
data(dat.bcg)

labs <- paste(dat.bcg$author, dat.bcg$year)
## labels with other strings

labs[2] <- paste0(intToUtf8(8804), "2")
#labs[3] <- expression(paste("<=4 ngml"^{-1}))
res <- rma(ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg, measure="RR", 
           method="REML")
forest(res, slab = labs)

Comment: Hmm. You could retain `labs` as a `character` vector by using `labs[3] <- paste0("x", intToUtf8(8804), "4 ngml", intToUtf8(8315), intToUtf8(185))`. Not perfect for everyday usage, but it works here.